# Call overrided methods of descendants from virtual destructor of base class

Tags: c++

Let's say we have codes like follow:

```
class Base{
public:
  virtual ~Base(){PutStat();};
  virtual void PutStat(){/* maybe do nothing */};
};

class Desend : public Base{
public:
  void PutStat() override{/* do something */};
};
```

Method PutStat will print some statistic. I hope every instance of Descendants inherited from Base could automatically print a statistic message while destructing.

It seems like a common feature here to output stat-message, so I think it's more reasonable to call PutStat just once in Base than call PutStat in each descendants separately.

Unfortunately, as destructor in Base is virtual, thus un-overrided PutSat will be called.

So how to call the overrided version of PutStat in Base destructor.

Comment: You can't. The destructor for the derived class has already run, so there's nothing sensible that a member function of the derived class can do.

Comment: You can't. At the point where the base class destructor is invoked, the derived object doesn't exist anymore and you will be calling the base class version of `PutStat`

Comment: And your destructor isn't virtual btw.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you. I think the needs I post here is real sometimes.

Comment: @MikeMB I've polished the codes.

Comment: @PeteBecker Would you like to post your answer as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @MikeMB Would you like to post your answer as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, as destructor in Base is virtual, thus un-overrided PutSat will be called.

Correct, but not for that reason. The destructor being virtual has nothing to do with it. The base class's methods will be called because the object has been partially destroyed back to the base class, which includes causing its VFT be that of a base class instance.

> How to call the overridden version

You can't. It's gone. The object has gone. It wouldn't make sense, so C++ doesn't allow it.